# VB6 Converting Long to Integer throwing overflow

Tags: vb6, casting, integer, long-integer

I am trying to convert a long to an integer. I believe the value of the long is low enough to fit in the range on an integer.

I have the code:

```
'mapdc is a long
Debug.Print mapdc
Debug.Print CInt(mapdc)
```

The first line runs fine. It outputs 1107367444.
The second line however causing an overflow error to happen.

Any ideas?
THANKS!!!!

Comment: Odd question to ask, this is pretty fundamental.  No "casting" involved, only conversion.  So this is tagged incorrectly.

Answer (score 7):

A VB6 `Integer` data type is 16-bits. You are causing an overflow: The value of `mapdc` is greater than `32,767` which falls outside of the range of values supported by an Integer variable. For more information on VB6 data types see [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263420%28v=vs.60%29.aspx).

Comment: +1 Here is the MSDN page on VB6 and VBA data types http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263420(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: @MarkJ - Thanks for that link. I added it to my anwser.

Answer (score 5):

The range of a VB6 Integer type is -32,768 to 32,767. Obviously, your value falls outside of that range and overflows.

[Data Types - VB 6 tutorial](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/32/data-types/)

MSDN Confirms by saying that a VB6 Integer corresponds to the .NET type of Int16 which has the same range:

[Integer Data Type for Visual Basic 6.0 Users](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f5ztkz3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Int in VB6 is 16 bit (range from -32,768 to 32,767). [This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f5ztkz3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) provides a comparison between VB6 with the .Net equivalents